# Trouble with back button

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiviewcontroller

I have strange trouble with my back button. I have 2 VC. Every VC has its own back button (they're not default, they are added as Left Bar Button Items. When I coming from VC1 (linked with Home View Controller, not shown) to VC2 I see VC2 but when I'm coming back to VC1 I see Navigation bar of VC1 and view of VC2. What Do I need to do to?
I also tried to add func but it hadn't helped.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { if segue.identifier == "comeBack" {
        let backVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionVC") as! RecipeCollectionViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(backVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why you want to have a back button for First controller ?

Comment: It's not First Controller. It's linked with Home View Controller

Comment: So when you click of your custom back button of VC2, are you writing the code shown in your question ? If that is the case, you shouldn't push your controller rather pop your controller.

Comment: Its wrong way to back from second to first, you dont create another segue, do like the answer below

Comment: to go back you only need to "self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) " and it will go back to previous viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

use this for push VC1 TO VC2

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC2") as! VC2
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

and use this for back from VC2 TO VC1

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: I have no troubles with pushing VC1 to VC2

Comment: self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)  use this in your back button

Answer (score 0):

For pop specific view controller

```
 let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
  for vc in viewControllers {
  if VC is YourViewController {
    self.navigationController!.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
 }
}
```

If Pop previous controller than use

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```